# SQLiteQueryBuilder return no results

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I use SQLiteQueryBuilder  to query information from my database with the following code

```
SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
builder.setTables("customers");
Cursor cursor = builder.query(database, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

but I didn't receive any element in cursor

and I am sure that there is data in database

what is the problems in my code ?

Comment: Did you really name your table `"CUSTOMERS_TABLE"` or is that supposed to be a variable?

Comment: why it first case you are using database and in second ataCollecterApp.database?

Comment: @MohammedSubhiSheikhQuroush  How are you verifying that you didn't receive any element in cursor?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to determine from what you've placed, but the most likely is the previous query you posted.

```
final static String CUSTOMERS_TABLE = "customers";
database.rawQuery("select * from CUSTOMERS_TABLE", null);
```

If this is what your code actually is, you need to concatenate your query with the constant, otherwise you will get no results because `CUSTOMERS_TABLE` doesn't exist, but `customers` does.

Something like this

```
final static String CUSTOMERS_TABLE = "customers";
database.rawQuery("select * from " + CUSTOMERS_TABLE, null);
```

Be careful here

- The first example will create the query `"select * from CUSTOMERS_TABLE"`
- The second example will create the query `"select * from customers"`

If you're still getting no results, you may actually have no data. Make sure to check that as well.

Comment: I use the first statementSQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
builder.setTables("customers");
Cursor cursor = builder.query(database, null, null, null, null, null, null); and it has not include the error that you mentioned and I still has no data and when I use the second statement database.rawQuery("select * from customers" , null); I got the data

Comment: You need to change `database.rawQuery("select * from CUSTOMERS_TABLE", null);` to `database.rawQuery("select * from " + CUSTOMERS_TABLE, null);`

Comment: no this command work for me but SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
builder.setTables("customers");
Cursor cursor = builder.query(database, null, null, null, null, null, null); doesn't work

Comment: Your code looks fine. Try `builder.setTables(CUSTOMERS_TABLE);`